# HTML email width issue in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, outlook-2013

I'm having a lot of trouble designing an HTML email for Outlook 2013. In all other email clients the table is displayed properly (even Outlook Web App) with the correct widths of the table and images. But in Outlook 2013 the entire table including images are compressed.

Below I've posted the first bit of my code. So I already wrapped the actual table with the email content, put all CSS inline and declared widths in without 'px'. I don't know what more there is to try.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML Email</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center"><tr><td width="100%">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0; border:0 none; border-radius:0;">
        <tr>
            <td width="596" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; padding: 5px;">Click here if this email isn't displayed properly.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="left "><img src="logo.png" width="150" height="48" /></a></td>
            <td width="50%" align="right"><img src="personen.png" width="70" height="70" />&nbsp;<img src="bord.png" width="70" height="70" />&nbsp;<img src="brood.png" width="70" height="70" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="596" colspan="2"><img src="visual.png" height="235" width="596" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="596" colspan="2" style="padding: 20px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)